# ASP.NET Core and legacy EF project with migrations

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I've just created a new ASP.NET Core API and I have a legacy EF project with a few migrations. I referenced it to the API project. Initially everything seemed fine (the project builds without errors and I can run it).

Now I want to add a new migration. I've tried to do it an old way using my EF project as a `-ProjectName` parameter but it didn't work.

Is it possible to use legacy EF project with ASP.NET Core and if yes how can I work with migrations now?